# Scrolling while input box is running

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro to show an input box to the user:

```
Sub InsertRows()
    Do
        row_number = InputBox("How many rows do you want to insert?" _
            & vbCr & "Max: 500")
        If row_number = "" Then Exit Sub
        If row_number > 500 Then MsgBox ("Row number has to be <= 500")
    Loop Until row_number <= 500 Or row_number = ""
    MsgBox (row_number & " Rows inserted successfully.")
End Sub
```

The macro itself works perfectly. However, once the input box is shown on the excel screen and the user has to put in a value he is not able to scroll within the sheet.

Is it possible to program this input box in a way so the user can still scroll within the sheet while the inputbox is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Application.InputBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839468.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which is quite similar but not modal